# Как оценить эффективность запроса по плану запроса?

Tags: sql-server

Как оценить эффективность запроса по плану запроса SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую почитать следующие статьи:

- [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)
- [Graphical Execution Plans for Simple SQL Queries](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/graphical-execution-plans-for-simple-sql-queries/)
- [Understanding More Complex Query Plans](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/understanding-more-complex-query-plans/)